# Prisma - The provided database string is invalid. MongoDB connection string error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm being told I have an invalid connection string for my MongoDB data provider.

Specifically, I'm getting this: `The provided database string is invalid. MongoDB connection string error: Missing delimiting slash between hosts and options in database URL.`

My problem, however, is that my connection string **does** have a delimiting slash: it's this: `mongodb://<user>:<pass>@cluster0.<server>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

What's going on? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's missing database name after host: `mongodb://<user>:<pass>@cluster0.<server>.mongodb.net/<mydb>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe i missed this...

Answer (score 8):

For someone who tried to connect mongodb in prisma, maybe you choose wrong connect , try to use type connect using VSCode

```
mongodb+srv://<admin>:<password>@cluster0.8hjts4c.mongodb.net/test
```

it must have `/test`

Comment: Thanks this worked! Life saver comment :3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongodb then just write database name as the path (replace `<name>` etc.)

```
mongodb://<user>:<pass>@cluster0.<server>.mongodb.net/<name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```